# Redux-Form Field won't update with value of <input> inside it

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to design a type-able input component in React, which is wrapped inside a Redux-Form `Field`. But the value of the `Field` doesn't update when the value of the HTML `<input>` tag changes.

The `Field` is defined as:

```
<Field
    name="inputTextBox"
    type="text"
    component={CustomInputComponent}
</Field>
```

And the `CustomInputComponent` is defined as:

```
    class CustomInputComponent extends Component {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state= {
                value: undefined
            };

        /* updates the state of CustomInputComponent with the current value typed inside <input> */
        setInputValueText = (value) => {
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                value
            })
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onInput={event => this.setInputValueText(event.target.value)} />
            )

    }
```

Whenever the `<input>` tag is typed into, the state of the `CustomInputComponent` changes successfully, but the value of the `Field` above that contains `CustomInputComponent` doesn't change. I am trying to access the value of the `Field` through:

```
const selector = formValueSelector('myForm')
let currentInput = selector(state, 'inputTextBox')
```

I want `currentInput` to contain the current value typed inside `input`. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to do it:

- Pass Redux Form **Field's data/methods** to **child** (recommended -- see below for minimum requirements).
- Utilize React state, set it to Redux field, then pass it from
  the **parent** to the **child**.

https://codesandbox.io/s/z3xnjv4w7m (passing Redux Field data/methods to child)
https://codesandbox.io/s/m4x7z7o429 (controlling Redux Fields through React state)

---

### **Pass Redux Field's Data/Methods to Child Example**

**InputForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import CustomInputComponent from "./customInputComponent";

const isRequired = value => (!value ? "Required" : undefined);

class InputForm extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit = ({ inputTextBox }) =>
    alert(`Value of custom input: ${inputTextBox}`);

  render = () => (
    <div style={{ height: 300, width: 500 }}>
      <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Input Form</h1>
      <hr />
      <Form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit)}>
        <div style={{ height: 70 }}>
          <Field
            className="uk-input"
            component={CustomInputComponent}
            name="inputTextBox"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Write something..."
            validate={[isRequired]}
          />
        </div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large"
          disabled={this.props.submitting}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large"
          disabled={this.props.pristine || this.props.submitting}
          onClick={this.props.reset}
          style={{ float: "right" }}
        >
          Clear
        </button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default reduxForm({ form: "InputForm" })(InputForm);
```

**customInputField.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

export default ({
  children,
  input,
  meta: { invalid, touched, error },
  ...props
}) => (
  <Fragment>
    <input {...input} {...props} />
    {touched && error && <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</div>}
  </Fragment>
```

### **Minimum Requirements**

At bare minimum, Redux Field's `input.onChange` method and `input.value` needs to be passed from parent to child.

**Parent**

```
<Field
   component={CustomInputComponent}
   name="inputTextBox"
/>
```

**Child**

```
export default ({ input: { onChange, value }}) => (
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Write something..."
    className="uk-input"
    onChange={onChange}
    value={value}
  />
);
```

---

### **Controlled Fields Through React State**

**ControlledInputForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Field, reduxForm, change } from "redux-form";
import CustomInputComponent from "./customInputComponent";

const isRequired = value => (!value ? "Required" : undefined);

class ControlledInputForm extends Component {
  state = { value: "" };

  handleFormSubmit = ({ inputTextBox }) =>
    alert(`Value of custom input: ${inputTextBox}`);

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value }, () => {
      this.props.change("inputTextBox", this.state.value);
    });
  };

  resetForm = () => this.setState({ value: "" }, () => this.props.reset());

  render = () => (
    <div style={{ height: 300, width: 500 }}>
      <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Controlled Input Form</h1>
      <hr />
      <Form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit)}>
        <div style={{ height: 70 }}>
          <Field
            className="uk-input"
            component={CustomInputComponent}
            name="inputTextBox"
            placeholder="Write something..."
            type="text"
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            controlledValue={this.state.value}
            validate={[isRequired]}
          />
        </div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large"
          disabled={this.props.submitting}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large"
          disabled={this.props.pristine || this.props.submitting}
          onClick={this.resetForm}
          style={{ float: "right" }}
        >
          Clear
        </button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "ControlledInputForm",
  fields: ["inputTextBox"]
})(ControlledInputForm);
```

**customInputComponent.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

export default ({
  meta: { invalid, touched, error },
  handleChange,
  controlledValue,
  ...props
}) => (
  <Fragment>
    <input {...props} value={controlledValue} onChange={handleChange} />
    {touched && error && <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</div>}
  </Fragment>
);
```